# Pygame: Rect Objects Don't Render Properly in For Loops

Tags: python, pygame, rendering, overlapping

I'm currently using Pygame to develop a game and I've decided that I'd group all my GUI objects together in a dictionary like so:

```
gui_objects = {
    # The GuiObject parameters define a rect (for positioning) and background colour.
    "healthbar" : GuiObject((10,  10, 100, 20), Colour.BLUE),
    "mini_map"  : GuiObject((10, 400,  50, 50), Colour.WHITE)
}
```

The reason I'm grouping GUI objects like this is so I can easily modify them like:

```
gui_objects.get("mini_map").set_enabled(false)
```

Now, when I want to render my GUI objects to the screen, I simply did this:

```
for key, value in gui_objects.iteritems():
    value.render(screen)
```

This works, but for some reason, the white "mini_map" GuiObject gets rendered underneath the "healthbar" GuiObject. I decided to put the "mini_map" above the "healthbar" in the dictionary, but that changed nothing. But now here's the weird part. If I render the GUI objects separately, that is, by calling their render() functions separately, like this:

```
gui_objects.get("healthbar").render(screen)
gui_objects.get("mini_map" ).render(screen)
```

Then the GuiObjects overlap properly. My question now is, why do my GuiObjects not overlap properly when I render them using the for loop? Yet they overlap just fine when rendered separately?

Unfortunately, I can't upload images because I don't have enough reputation ¬_¬ But, here's the source code:

```
import pygame

# Just a definition of a few colours
class Colour(object):
    WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
    GREY  = (128, 128, 128)
    BLUE  = ( 64, 128, 255)

# GuiObject is just a rectangle with a colour at the moment (for testing purposes).
class GuiObject(object):
    def __init__(self, rect, colour):
        self.rect   = rect
        self.colour = colour

    def render(self, screen):
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, self.colour, self.rect)

def main():
    ############################################################################
    # Initialise
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))

    # if render_type = 0 then render GuiObjects using a for loop
    # if render_type = 1 then render GuiObjects separately.
    render_type = 1

    gui_objects = {
        "hpbar_bg"    : GuiObject(( 0,  0, 150, 600), (Colour.BLUE)),
        "enemy_hpbar" : GuiObject((10, 10, 200, 400), (Colour.WHITE)),
    }

    ############################################################################
    # Main loop
    while True:
        ########################################################################
        # Event Handling
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                exit(0)

        ########################################################################
        # Render
        screen.fill((0, 0, 0))

        # Here, I render the GuiObjects.
        if render_type == 0:
            # This for loop messes up overlapping.
            for key, value in gui_objects.iteritems():
                value.render(screen)
        elif render_type == 1:
            # This works fine.
            gui_objects.get("hpbar_bg").render(screen)
            gui_objects.get("enemy_hpbar").render(screen)

        pygame.display.flip()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Has anyone got a clue as to why overlapping GuiObjects doesn't work properly when using the for loop?

I hope I've explained myself clearly enough. If not, just ask and I'll try to clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because dictionaries aren't ordered and it is drawing the objects in a different order than your other method.

A dictionary is just not designed for holding objects that need to stay in order.

You can either:

1. Use a pygame render [group](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group) instead.

This would be the pygame-recommended way to store groups of objects that are going to be drawn, however you would have to convert your GUI objects into sprites I believe. EDIT: Also, pygame render groups are still not ordered so this wouldn't solve your particular problem.

2. Use a list of tuples `[(name,value),...]` instead (this will be the most similar to your current method because that's actually what the `iteritems()` dictionary method returns).

Here is your code re-written using method 2:

```
import pygame

# Just a definition of a few colours
class Colour(object):
    WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
    GREY  = (128, 128, 128)
    BLUE  = ( 64, 128, 255)

# GuiObject is just a rectangle with a colour at the moment (for testing purposes).
class GuiObject(object):
    def __init__(self, rect, colour):
        self.rect   = rect
        self.colour = colour

    def render(self, screen):
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, self.colour, self.rect)

def main():
    ############################################################################
    # Initialise
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))

    # if render_type = 0 then render GuiObjects using a for loop
    # if render_type = 1 then render GuiObjects separately.
    render_type = 0

    gui_objects = [
        ("hpbar_bg", GuiObject(( 0,  0, 150, 600), (Colour.BLUE))),
        ("enemy_hpbar", GuiObject((10, 10, 200, 400), (Colour.WHITE))),
    ]

    ############################################################################
    # Main loop
    while True:
        ########################################################################
        # Event Handling
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                exit(0)

        ########################################################################
        # Render
        screen.fill((0, 0, 0))

        # Here, I render the GuiObjects.
        if render_type == 0:
            # This for loop no longer messes up overlapping.
            for key, value in gui_objects:
                value.render(screen)

        pygame.display.flip()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Because you would like to be able to do things like `gui_objects.hpbar_bg.set_enabled(False)` then I would look into a third option:

3. Restructuring your code to contain the GUI within a class itself, and then order the drawing of its components within its draw method.

Here is an example of 3 that doesn't deviate too far from what you've got:

```
import pygame

# Just a definition of a few colours
class Colour(object):
    WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
    GREY  = (128, 128, 128)
    BLUE  = ( 64, 128, 255)

# GuiObject is just a rectangle with a colour at the moment (for testing purposes).
class GuiObject(object):
    def __init__(self, rect, colour):
        self.rect   = rect
        self.colour = colour
        self.enabled = True

    def render(self, screen):
        if self.enabled:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, self.colour, self.rect)

class Gui(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.hpbar_bg = GuiObject(( 0,  0, 150, 600), (Colour.BLUE))
        self.enemy_hpbar = GuiObject((10, 10, 200, 400), (Colour.WHITE))
        self.enabled = True

    def render(self, screen):
        #render my gui in the order i want
        if self.enabled:
            self.hpbar_bg.render(screen)
            self.enemy_hpbar.render(screen)


def main():
    ############################################################################
    # Initialise
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))

    gui = Gui()

    #uncomment to get the enabled/disabled behavior
    #gui.hpbar_bg.enabled = False

    #or disable the whole gui
    #gui.enabled = False

    ############################################################################
    # Main loop
    while True:
        ########################################################################
        # Event Handling
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                exit(0)

        ########################################################################
        # Render
        screen.fill((0, 0, 0))

        # Render GUI
        gui.render(screen)

        pygame.display.flip()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply. I didn't realise that dictionaries didn't preserve the order of items :( I think I'll give your 3rd method a go. Thanks for the help!

Comment: You could also use an OrderedDict which records the order in which items are added, but having them all in one class is a far better solution.